# How do I get the property names of a class

Tags: javascript

I have a class Product. I wanna create a table which have column names same as class field names.
product.ts

```
export class Product{
 public id:number;
 public name:string;
 }
```

product.component.html

```
<th *ngFor="let column of columns">
 <tr>
     {{column}}
 </tr>
```

product.component.ts
`public columns = [];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a JavaScript question rather than an Angular question.

The best resource for JavaScript and other browser platform documentation is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

The specific answer is

```
Object.keys(instance)
```

This works for most JavaScript objects like class instances.

```
person = new Person(5, 'Joe Blow' );
columns = Object.keys(person);
```